# select only one row that has the highest count in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to select one row only which has the highest count. How do I do that?

This is my current code:

```
 select firstname, lastname, count(*) as total
 from trans 
 join work 
 on trans.workid = work.workid
 join artist
 on work.artistid = artist.artistid
 where datesold is not null
 group by firstname, lastname;
```

Example current:

```
FIRSTNAME |  LASTNAME |  TOTAL
------------------------------
Tom       |   Cruise  |   3
Angelina  |   Jolie   |   9
Britney   |   Spears  |   5
Ellie     |  Goulding |   4
```

I need it to select only this:

```
FIRSTNAME  |  LASTNAME  |  TOTAL
--------------------------------
Angelina   |  Jolie     |   9
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgresql, other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 12, you can do:

```
 select firstname, lastname, count(*) as total
 from trans join
      work 
      on trans.workid = work.workid join
      artist
      on work.artistid = artist.artistid
 where datesold is not null
 group by firstname, lastname
 order by count(*) desc
 fetch first 1 row only;
```

In older versions, you can do this with a subquery:

```
select twa.*
from (select firstname, lastname, count(*) as total
      from trans join
           work 
           on trans.workid = work.workid join
           artist
           on work.artistid = artist.artistid
      where datesold is not null
      group by firstname, lastname
      order by count(*) desc
     ) twa
where rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `order by total desc` and `fetch first 1 row only` (*since Oracle 12c r1 only*, otherwise you should use your result as temp table and `select` from it to use `rownum = 1` limitation in the `where` clause) , in case you `total` can't be the same for different groups. The other way is to add this `having` clause, so you can list all people with maximum `total`:

```
having count(*) = (select max(total) from (select count(*) as total from <your_query>) tmp)
```

or that:

```
having count(*) = (select count(*) as total from <your_query> order by total desc fetch first 1 row only)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work sql server 2012..

```html
with CTECount (firstname, lastname,total)
as
(
 select firstname, lastname, count(1) as total
  from trans 
  join work 
  on trans.workid = work.workid
  join artist
  on work.artistid = artist.artistid
  where datesold is not null
  group by firstname, lastname
 )

 select top(1) with ties from CTECount 
 order by total desc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this, very simple:

select **TOP 1** firstname, lastname, count(*) as total from trans
join work on trans.workid=work.workid
join artist on work.artistid=artist.artistid
where datesold is not null
group by firstname, lastname
**Order By Total DESC**;